Why Tensorflow SavedModel is a directory
People who designed the SavedModelBundle definitely had a very good reason to make it export and load models to a directory on a disk. However doesn't this defeat the very important purpose of portability? Isn't passing around the graph and weights in a single file like they did in Tensorflow V1 a better approach for that? I think the new approach is better suited in case of using suggested sharing and deploying tools by TensorFlow like TensorFlow Serving, but in a custom-made pipeline, passing around those models need extra steps and would require slow IO operations.
